# Complex measures and finite signed measures

Tags: measure-theory

If $\nu$ is a complex measure on $(X,M)$ and $\nu(X)=|\nu|(X)$, then prove that $\nu=|\nu|$.

So, if $\mu$ is a finite signed measure then we have $\mu^-(X)=0$ and hence $\mu=|\mu|$. 
So, if $\nu_r$ and $\nu_i$ are the real and imaginary parts of $\nu$, then they are finite signed measures. If I can show that $\nu_r(X)=|\nu_r|(X)$ and $\nu_i(X)=|\nu_i|(X)$ then we have $\nu_r=|\nu_r|$ and $\nu_i=|\nu_i|$. Then given $E\in M$, $\nu(E)=|\nu_r|(E)+i|\nu_i|(E)$.

Then this implies $|\nu|(X)=|\nu_r|(X)+i|\nu_i|(X)$. So, $|\nu_i|(X)=0$ and hence $|\nu_i|(E)=0$. That means, $\nu(E)=|\nu_r|(E)$.

So, $\nu$ is a positive measure and hence, $\nu=|\nu|$.

But now I am stuck in proving $\nu_r(X)=|\nu_r|(X)$ and $\nu_i(X)=|\nu_i|(X)$. Can anyone please help me?